# php sql value is empty redirect

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table called recruiting with a field called `rct_app_uid` and `rct_app_id`, if there is no `rct_app_id` for the user I want the request to be redirected. If `rct_app_id` have value  and is the same as `rct_app_uid`, the request wont be redirected.

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['uid'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM recruiting WHERE rct_app_uid = $user_id";
    $result = query($sql);

    while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))!=false){
        echo $rct_app_uid = $row['rct_app_uid'];

        if ($rct_app_uid >0){

            return true;

        } else {

            redirect(ROOT_URI);

        }
    }
```

Comment: What's in the definition of your `redirect()` function?

Comment: http://localhost/cms/  I use the same redirect through out but for some reason it wont redirect if the field is empty

Comment: would 0 still refer to a empty field that has no value at all?

Comment: is your redirect a function? if not your header('location: '.ROOT_URI.');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this use mysqli_num_rows instead

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['uid'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM recruiting WHERE rct_app_uid = $user_id";
$result = query($sql);


if (mysqli_num_rows($result) >0){

    return true;

} else {

  redirect(ROOT_URI);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

is your redirect a function? if not use header() function

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['uid'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM recruiting WHERE rct_app_uid = $user_id";
$result = query($sql);

while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))!=false){
    echo $rct_app_uid = $row['rct_app_uid'];

    if ($rct_app_uid >0){

        return true;

    } else {

        header('location: '.ROOT_URI);

    }
}
```

Comment: still not redirecting

Comment: try echo ROOT_URI;exit(); after header('location: '.ROOT_URI);

Comment: i think its looking for a 0 but there is nothing in that table at all

Comment: so the mistake here is your query

Comment: try changing your query to 
  SELECT count(*) as count FROM recruiting WHERE rct_app_uid = $user_id

Comment: after that change your condition to if ($row['count'])

Comment: I figured out what is wrong if i change the rct_app_id to 0 it will redirect but since the field is blank it wont redirect